# How to hide 3rd party imports from pdoc?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8, docstring, pdoc

What is the proper way to hide imports from a documentation generator like pdoc?

Specifically, what is best practice for generating docs on adhoc scripts?

For example:

```
import someThirdPartyLibrary

def main():
    someThirdPartyLibrary.somefunc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

One needs to have `someThirdPartyLibrary` installed in the environment *or pdoc will FAIL.*

The options seem to be:

A. Install all 3rd party libraries to whatever environment I'm running pdoc from. This seems totally unnecessary since pdoc doesn't need to actually *run* the code only load it.

B. Hide imports in main and violate PEP8

```
def main():
    import someThirdPartyLibrary
    someThirdPartyLibrary.somefunc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

C. Something better than A and B that is best practice?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but [pdoc](https://pdoc.dev) needs to import your code to parse out (dynamic) annotations. As such, I would really recommend to just go with option A: install all third-party libraries.